# Spark Scala : Modify the structure of nested struct in scala

Tags: arrays, json, scala, apache-spark, struct

............................
Below is the nested struct that I have.
............................

Code Structure

```
 |-- Country: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- India: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Chennai: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- lat: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- long: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Mumbai: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- lat: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- long: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Delhi: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- lat: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- long: double (nullable = true)
 |    |-- US: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Alaska: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- lat: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- long: double (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- California: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- lat: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- long: double (nullable = true)
```

The expected output is
..................................

Expected output:
`{"India": {"Chennai": [145.034, 267.856], "Mumbai": [673.67, 452.887], "Delhi": [563.67, 452.298]},  "US": {"Alaska": [865.264, 292.085], "California": [752.478, 197.085]}}`

...................................

How to achieve this in scala if there are many different countries with different number of cities.

I tried with to_json function and I got below output. Tried many ways but unable to bring it to above format. How can this be achieved in a simple and efficient way

........................................

Received output:

{"India": {"Chennai": {"lat":145.034, "long":267.856}, "Mumbai": {"lat":673.67, "long":452.887}, "Delhi": {"lat":563.67, "long":452.298}},
"US": {"Alaska": {"lat":865.264, "long":292.085}, "California": {"lat":752.478, "long":197.085}}}

..........................................

Comment: Create a case class with the schema and do the change using an udf. You could also use spark sql functions.

Comment: @EmilianoMartinez Can you please provide the code. It would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, we group the DataFrame df by the "Country" column and collect the corresponding "City" values into an array called "Cities" using collect_list.

Then, we use the withColumn function to create a new column "CityData" by mapping the "Cities" array to a map using the map_from_arrays function. The "Cities" array serves as the keys, and we collect the corresponding struct of "lat" and "long" columns using collect_list(struct(lat, long)).

Finally, we group by an empty sequence groupBy() and aggregate the data by constructing the desired nested map structure using map_from_arrays with "Country" as the keys and "CityData" as the values. The result is named "CountryData".

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

// Assuming your DataFrame is named "df"

// Define the schema for the expected output
val schema = new StructType()
  .add("Country", new MapType(StringType,
    new MapType(StringType,
      new ArrayType(new DoubleType, containsNull = false), valueContainsNull = false)))

// Group the data by country and city, collect the latitude and longitude into arrays
val grouped = df.groupBy("Country").agg(collect_list(col("City")).as("Cities"))
  .withColumn("CityData", expr("map_from_arrays(Cities, collect_list(struct(lat, long)))"))
  .groupBy().agg(map_from_arrays(collect_list(col("Country")), collect_list(col("CityData"))).as("CountryData"))

// Convert the grouped data to JSON using the defined schema
val result = grouped.select(to_json(struct(col("CountryData"))).cast(StringType)).as[String]

// Print the result
result.show(truncate = false)
```

Comment: error: constructor DoubleType in class DoubleType cannot be accessed in class $iw.
 
This is the issue I am facing when I execute "val schema"

Comment: Also the schema structure has only "Country" and "lat" "long" . CountryData and CityData is not explicitly specified.

This is how the data looks when we flatten it

(Country{"India": {"Chennai": {"lat":145.034, "long":267.856}, "Mumbai": {"lat":673.67, "long":452.887}, "Delhi": {"lat":563.67, "long":452.298}}, "US": {"Alaska": {"lat":865.264, "long":292.085}, "California": {"lat":752.478, "long":197.085}}}}

We have only "Country" and "lat","long" fields in data